# Booting WDS Capture image on VM Gen2

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, imaging, netboot

Have problem booting capture image, created by Microsoft WDS management console. I **have functional boot image** (boot.wim) taken from WinServer 2012 R2 iso. This image works fine on Hyper-V Gen2 VM. But when I create **capture image from working image**, I am **unable to boot and start the capture image** on that same VM.

I have already made well-known fix of well-known MS bug (see [this](http://dave.harris.uno/capture-error-0xc000000f-with-wds-on-server-2012-r2/)) -  Status: 0xc000000f durring boot. I dont get this error anymore. But have another one:

After the capture image is successfuly downloaded from WDS server (progress bar), it tries to start the image (Hyper-V logo and spinner) for a while, but than I got **blank black screen**.

Comment: Have installed Windows Server 2008 R2 on virtual machine and have deployed capture image using 2008 R2 WDS management console. Working perfectly. Microsoft go f**k yourself!

Comment: Have you tried MDT? I would recommend it for all of your imaging needs (MDT= Microsoft Deployment Toolkit) it is free and integrates with WDS for a great WinPE based imaging system. Hope this helps!